# Use python and selenium to delete my comments in reddit

Tags: python, selenium, reddit

I am trying to write a script to delete all my comments on my profile in Reddit.

So I am currently using `Selenium` to log-in and try to delete my comments, however I am stuck at the point when after my script press delete on my comment and it changes to "Are you sure Yes/No" then it can't find the "Yes" element by `Xpath`. The following code throws the error:

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
>   Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
>   Stacktrace:

My code is as follows:

```
    del_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'thing_"+delete_type+"')]//div[2]/ul/li[7]/form/span[1]/a")
    del_button.click()        
    time.sleep(3)
    yes_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'thing_"+delete_type+"')]//div[2]/ul/li[7]/form/span[1]//a[1]")
    yes_button.click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Show `HTML` code of mentioned button

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="yes" onclick="change_state(this, &quot;del&quot;, hide_thing, undefined, null)">ja</a>

Comment: Can you try just `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="yes"]').click()`. Same result?

Comment: Yeah I tried both that and //*[contains(@id,'thing_"+delete_type+"')]//a[@class='yes'] Both give the same result unfortunately.

Comment: Tell me what is output of `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="yes"]')))`

Comment: No idea, why but that gives me: SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier Sec trying to figure out whats wrong with that.

Comment: Try to re-type `")))"` part manually as sometimes when you copy code from `StackOverflow` it might contain hidden invalid characters

Comment: Got it! Thanks. The result is: 4

Comment: Ok. There could be similar elements on page, but only one might be actually visible. Try to check each of them as `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="yes"]')‌​[0].click()`, `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="yes"]')‌[1].click()​`... Does it work for one of the elements?

Comment: You are the man, it worked! Can I ask though why does this work? And the other method does not?

Comment: `find_element_by_xpath()` finds only the first web-element matched with specified `XPath` while you might need second, third... I added the same as an answer. Please mark it as `Accepted` if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there could be several hidden elements with same attributes on page, you might need to use `index` to click on exact element:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="yes"]')‌​[N].clic‌​k() # N is the index of target link
```

I f you can't define exact index, you can use below code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException

for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="yes"]')‌:
    try:
        link.click()
        break
    except ElementNotVisibleException:
        pass
```

Comment: I am using a variation of this, thank you very much! Is there a specific reason for why it cant see them without the indexing? I found that very odd and it is something that has happened to me before.

Comment: You can avoid using indexes. You just have to define unique selector for the link. If parent element has several child elements with exactly the same `HTML`, indexing is the easiest way

Comment: Okay, but why does it state that the element is not visible? Except when I use index

Comment: Do you use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="yes"]')‌​[1].click()` ? What is the code that works properly?

Comment: Both of your code works. It is kinda weird, because sometimes it is nr 1 and other times it is 2. I did:             for nr_input_var in range(30):
                try:
                    driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="yes"]')[nr_input_var].click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    break
                except:
                    pass

Comment: Your `XPath` (from question) `"//*[contains(@id,'thing_"+delete_type+"')]//div[2]/ul/li[7]/form/span[1]//a[1]"` means **first** (`[1]`) matched link as in `XPath` indexing starts from `1` while in `Python` `list` indexing starts from `0` and you can successfully click on **second** (`[1]`) or **third** (`[2]`) matched link. That's why your initial code doesn't work

Comment: Ah okay, so it is simply just because it cant find the first instance. I copied it from google chrome Xpath, so I assumed it would take the right Xpath. Thanks for your help!